# Elasticsearch querying documents between two range fields of strings

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a log file stored in Elasticsearch, where a document is a single line of the file. Blocks of messages start and end with certain keywords. I want to get all documents between documents containing these keywords. Is there a way to leverage the range query/range filter in Elasticsearch to query for text fields?

Sample log file:
...
...
xyz foo "keyword1" .....
..
....
...
xyz bar "keyword2" .....
..
..

I'd like to query all documents between "keyword1" and "keyword2", including the documents containing the keywords themselves. Assume that there are multiple such blocks with "keyword1" and "keyword2".

Additionally, I'm updating the documents containing these keywords with a new field *test_field*, which contains these keywords as values. Can this new field be used in range filters to achieve the above task?

*Elasticsearch fields: _source: { "log_line", "test_field" }*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you also have some identifier that defines the order of those documents. Let's say, you have a field `line_number`.

You could do first two searches, matching all the documents containing the keywords. Then for each pair of those keywords you have starting and ending line number. For each pair you can search for for all documents between the two line numbers (using `range query`).
This wouldn't be a pure ES solution and requires some scripting in e.g. python or any other language. Let me know, if you need help with the queries.

But before doing something like this, if I were you, I would critically question this requirement. Why reading the logfile line for line into ES? Why not using Logstash/Filebeat to load the data with your preferred pattern, so you have one document with the whole block? Makes queries and analysis so much easier :)

Comment: Yes, I've tried the line_number method by using range query and extracting them in python, but I was hoping for some way to do it in pure ES since I'll be working with real-time log files which will be constantly updated with new lines. 

Currently my application is storing all log file data as Kafka messages in topics (Kafka is being used for some other stuff as well), so I was looking to do this directly in ES without adding another component (Logstash) into the mix.

Comment: How would reading multiple lines as single documents help in ES querying btw?

Comment: Okay, probably I misunderstood the question a little bit. I thought all lines between those two keywords belong to a single log message. In that case, it would make sense to put those multiple lines, as they belong together, into a single document. But I guess thats not the case.

Comment: Ah okay, so there isnt a pure ES solution that I can implement here?

Comment: At least nothing that I can think of. Sounds like a "subselect" in SQL, and as far as I know that's not possible in ES. But maybe there are some fancy script solutions..
Only solutions that come to my head would require more data preparation or transformation when loading to the index.

Comment: Oh okay alright, would I be able to do this in Logstash? The log files I'm reading have many different structures i.e it can be considered as semi-structured, which is why I was looking into Elasticsearch in the first place. If logstash can simplify the ingestion of logs and allow me to solve my problem, I have no problem bringing it into my stack.

Comment: That pretty much depends on your requirements and your data, but until now it never disappointed me. At least Logstash is made for parsing Log data.